# Can I cut out asphalt driveway to lay brick?

Tags: brick, driveway, pavers, asphalt

I just purchased a house and want to remove the asphalt driveway and lay down brick instead for three reasons:

First, the existing driveway is very narrow in some places and I want to widen it. Second, because the asphalt is getting old and has cracked in several areas, and last because part of the driveway is on a steep decline and when it's wet out it is very slick and my truck will spin tires trying to get out.

My question is, can I cut sections of asphalt out with a circular saw and immediately replace with brick or will there need to be additional work done to prep the surface? Thank you!

Comment: Depends how fast you'd like the brick to fail. Does it ever freeze?

Comment: Yes, it's in Virginia. I would prefer the brick fail long in the future!

Comment: One thing at a time. Cut out old, prep, lay. Doing anything else will ultimately take longer or will result in shoddy work.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want to do is basically build a paver driveway.  Hard to do in small sections, given that you need to lay a 6"+ gravel base, with a sand leveling layer.

Answer (score 1):

Any road (a driveway is a small road) is only as good as its base.

Since the asphalt is falling apart, the base under it is probably inadequate for asphalt, and generally bricks need an even better base, as they have no flexibility. That tends to look like digging out soil and replacing it with compacted rock. Depending on the site, drainage may also be needed.

On the third hand, if the driveway is so steep that you're spinning tires on asphalt, there's not much chance that merely changing to bricks will help much, if any, with that - bricks as paving can and do wear (and attract moss growth) to be smooth and slippery, so looking at fixing the grading of the whole driveway while you are fixing the base  would be a better plan, regardless of paving material.

Where there  is snowfall, and snow removal, bricks may be considerably less suitable than asphalt or concrete, as they are prone to damage from snowplows. If you limit snow removal to brush, shovel or snowblower you might be able to use brick.